# How to install python packages in a python install that's not managed by a virtual env

Tags: python, numpy, pip, nuke

One of the applications I use often, Nuke, has its own personal install of python. It's located at "/Applications/Nuke14.0v2/Nuke14.0v2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9""

I'm wanting to install the numpy package for this particular python install so I can use it in Nuke.

I can make this install my main python by putting an alias in my .zshrc file, but when I

`pip install numpy`

It still tries to install numpy in the anaconda install.

Could I make a venv and enter into it using this particular python install?

Comment: `/Applications/Nuke14.0v2/Nuke14.0v2.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9 -m pip install numpy`?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc Great read on why -m is so important